I need to have both English and German in Libreoffice spell check
I have installed the language packs for both, however I also need to have both activated at the same time. In the options I can only select one language at a time. Isn't it possible to have spell check active for both at all times?

Yes, it's possible - but for "mixed-language" text, you'll need to apply the appropriate styles. Spell checking depends on the language of the paragraph style or character style. Usually, the default language settings determine the language settings of paragraph styles. If you want to have German words spellchecked inside an English-language paragraph, you'll have to create a character style with German language settings (see the "font" tab) and apply it to the German-language parts of the paragraph.

